# Where are the most common OOP concepts implemented in java swing jframes?

Tags: java, swing, oop

i currently studying oop in java and i read in a book that java swing jframes are good to understand how oop works in creating gui's in a java program,so where are the following mostly implemeted.
I have done some research and i found some oop concepts implemeting in java

Inheritance - obviously a class need to inherit javax.swing.jframe to use all the methods.

Encapsulation - after creating buttons,panels e.t.c all of them have private access modifiers

So where are

- Association &Aggregation
- Polymorphism
- Abstraction & Interface

utilised?

Comment: This question is off topic because it's asking to recommend or find a OOP concepts. Things like these can be found with a [Google search](https://www.google.com.mx/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=java%20association)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. **Aggregation**  -   JFrame has a JPanel
2. **Composition** - JFrame has a JButton
   (composition because JButton cannot exist without a frame)
3. **Polymorphism** - Sometimes parameters are passed to methods which are asking in more generic way for example `someMethod(Component comp)` for comp we can pass a JButton (Because JButton IS-A Component)
4. **Abstraction/Interface** sometimes it is needed to implement interfaces and abstract classes, there you have to override all the abstract methods.

Comment: Not clear on 4th point which component is performing the action of abstraction, i understand interfaces are used by runnable() for creating forms but where is abstraction utilised in swing

Comment: @Franco To run GUI we normally use java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater, there we have to pass a Runnable as the parameter . Runnable is an interface that you have to override the abstract run method